# zsh: command not found: cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

Following this guide https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#macos for Mac OS X. Have completed all steps as per guide. However, I am getting 'zsh: command not found: cardano-cli'.

cardano-cli and cardano-node are clearly in /~.local/bin as you can see below.

```
ls -l ~/.local/bin
total 160128
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dylankumar  staff  36328576 18 Sep 11:48 cardano-cli
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dylankumar  staff  45651344 18 Sep 11:48 cardano-node
```

and ~/.local/bin is in path

```
echo $PATH
~/.local/bin/:/Users/dylankumar/.cabal/bin:/Users/dylankumar/.ghcup/bin:~/.local/bin/:~/.local/bin/:/Users/dylankumar/.cabal/bin:/Users/dylankumar/.ghcup/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

So I don't know why it's not working. I have have also restarted my computer, but am still getting:

```
# cardano-cli --version
cardano-node --version
zsh: command not found: cardano-cli
zsh: command not found: cardano-node
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Added `path+=~/.local/bin/.` to the bottom of my ~/.zshrc file, and now working.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the two files directly to the path. For `zsh` this can be configured in the `~/.zshrc` file.

Instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530176/10069673

Comment: Sweet, thanks, that worked. Added `path+=~/.local/bin/.` to bottom of my ~/.zshrc file.

Answer (score 0):

Read my medium story to find out how to configure [*.zshrc*](https://medium.com/geekculture/cardano-911-wallet-command-line-interface-part-one-ad0ee5ac8509) file in macOS.